# Speaker diarization tool for acoustic analysis

Tags: audio, speech-processing, speech, source-separation

I'm researching certain acoustic prosodic features during live clinical interactions. Because of the setting, the recordings always have cross channel bleed, and in some cases everything is recorded on one channel (e.g., collaborations with people that have a video database).

I need to diarize the speakers for audio analysis, but I don't have the skills to do it myself. I was wondering if you know any tools I can use for that, it doesn't have to be free, but I don't have a big budget.

I have tried the LIUM tool, which gives me a .seg file, but I'm not entirely sure what to do with it (I need two separate audio files), especially because it doesn't seem to have diarized my audio correctly.

Thank you!